# limit of a sequence whose terms follow a recurrence relation??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_0=a,x_1=b$
 and for $n\geq 0$,
$$3x_{n+2}=x_n+2x_{n+1}$$
then what is $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$?
Please if someone could help?

Comment: The limit of what? $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$? Also, what are your own thoughts on this? What have you tried? In what context did you encounter this problem? What do you know about this kind of problems?

Comment: sorry.is it right now?

Comment: Have you tried this for some $a,b$? Can you conjecture anything? (PS I don't think you want the limit of $x_n$ as this probably goes to infinity)

Comment: i just thought that if the limit exists then it should be same but thal makes me come to a case that l=l,where l is the limit

Comment: Is $a,b>0$ or  any $a,b \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Try calculating $x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ when $x_0=a=1$ and $x_1=b=2$. What do you see? Can you conjecture anything about (these) specific values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: a,b are any number on real line

Comment: they are coming out to be $1, 2, 5/3, 16/9,47/27$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting the recurrence, we have:

$x_{n} = \frac{2}{3}x_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}x_{n-2}$ which has the associated characteristic polynomial:

$x^2-\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}=0$ which factors as $(x-1)(x+\frac{1}{3})=0$

This implies that the closed form should look like:

$x_n = \alpha (1)^n + \beta(-\frac{1}{3})^n$ for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be determined from initial conditions.

This implies that as $n\to\infty$ you have $x_n\to \alpha$ as the second term on the right $\beta(-\frac{1}{3})^n$ tends to zero as $n$ grows large.

Given an initial $x_0=a$ and $x_1=b$, try solving for $\alpha$ using a system of two equations and two unknowns.

$\begin{cases}x_0=a=\alpha + \beta\\
x_1=b=\alpha-\frac{1}{3}\beta\end{cases}$

You can then express the limit $x_n\to\alpha$ as some function of $a$ and $b$.

> First line plus three times the second yields $a+3b = 4\alpha$, so $\alpha = \frac{a+3b}{4}$